# What does "a fine one" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The distinction between an appropriate gift and a bribe can be a fine
>   one.

It's about anti-bribery, and what does "fine one" mean here? Does it mean "Distinguishing between an appropriate gift and a bribe can be useful"?

Comment: What is the subject of your sentence?  The verb is "can be"; what noun "can be a fine one"?  Once you figure that out, look up *fine* in a dictionary.  After you've done that, let us know if you're still confused about the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @Juhasz It is the very first sentence. That's why it is confusing me. Just "fine one" is hard to understand, and of course I looked up dictionary to find any meaning that makes sense in this context. I still have no idea what it means.

Comment: The distinction between an appropriate gift and a bribe can be a fine distinction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construction *NOUN can be an ADJECTIVE one* essentially means the same thing as *it's possible that NOUN is ADJECTIVE.*

In this sentence, using the simpler phrase we'd get: "It's possible that the distinction is fine."

The appropriate definition of *fine* in this context is:

> **fine** *adjective*
>
> 3 : delicate, subtle, or sensitive in quality, perception, or discrimination
> // a *fine* distinction
>
> https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fine

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever he buys a new car he gets *a red one*.
>
> If you're going to give your teacher an apple, give *one* without a worm in it.
>
> I'd like a cup of coffee please. Not one of those buckets. Make it *a small one*.
>
> Is that snake a poisonous one?

**one** = member of the mentioned set